# How can I get a list of all DLLs searchable via probing privatePath?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

A probing path is being used to specify define locations of various integration dlls.

Is there a simple means to get a list of every dll filename that the probing privatePath will make available when assemblies are loaded?

Comment: What is `privatePath`? That looks like a variable name for some function but you never told us what function you are calling. Are you talking about `lpPathName` from [SetDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Info on privatePath here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Please include that information in the question itself instead of just in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is available via the AppDomain's SetupInformation

```
SetupInformation.PrivateBinPathProbe
SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup(v=vs.110).aspx